# I have error In timezone setting

Tags: php, date, datetime, object, timezone

I m using following code.

> static::$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get() ?: 'UTC');
>
> 'datetime' => \DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf('%.6F', microtime(true)), static::$timezone)->setTimezone(static::$timezone),

but I m getting error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setTimezone() on a non-object

So what is wrong in the code

Comment: `->setTimezone` is not needed, just make sure `static::$timezone` is indeed a `DateTimezone` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `->setTimeZone` there. Just make sure `static::$timezone` is indeed a `DateTimeZone` object since you already fed it with that:

```
static::$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Then on creating the DateTime object:

```
'datetime' => \DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf('%.6F', microtime(true)), static::$timezone)
```